# How to perform point-in-time recovery in PostgreSQL with PgBackRest and repmgr

Tags: postgresql, restore, repmgr

I have such setup:

- 2 VM with Rocky Linux 8 for PostgreSQL Primary + Standby setup
- PostgreSQL 15 from official rpm repo
- [repmgr](http://www.repmgr.org/) for replication
- [PgBackRest](https://pgbackrest.org) for backups to S3 (minio instance)

My goal is to find out how to restore to a specific backup.

I performed such actions:

1. Setup test db with data from [pagila](https://github.com/devrimgunduz/pagila)
2. Make full backup with `sudo -u postgres pgbackrest --stanza=cluster --log-level-console=info --type=full backup`
3. Drop `film` table: `drop table film cascade;`

At this point I want to restore to the backup.

```
[root@rocky2 ~]# sudo -u postgres pgbackrest --stanza=cluster info
stanza: cluster
    status: ok
    cipher: none

    db (current)
        wal archive min/max (15): 000000010000000000000001/00000003000000000000000B

        full backup: 20231228-165042F
            timestamp start/stop: 2023-12-28 16:50:42 / 2023-12-28 16:51:32
            wal start/stop: 000000010000000000000005 / 000000010000000000000006
            database size: 36.4MB, database backup size: 36.4MB
            repo1: backup set size: 4.8MB, backup size: 4.8MB

        full backup: 20231228-171910F
            timestamp start/stop: 2023-12-28 17:19:10 / 2023-12-28 17:20:04
            wal start/stop: 000000010000000000000009 / 000000010000000000000009
            database size: 47.7MB, database backup size: 47.7MB
            repo1: backup set size: 7.3MB, backup size: 7.3MB
```

1. Stop PostgreSQL on primary and standby: `systemctl stop postgresql-15`
2. Remove all data files: `find /var/lib/pgsql/15/data -mindepth 1 -delete`
3. Restore to the latest backup: `sudo -u postgres pgbackrest --stanza=cluster restore`
4. Start primary again

Unfortunately PostgreSQL had applied all WAL records from S3, so `film` table does not exist anymore.

I tried to perform point-in-time restore:

1. Take a loook at backup start timestamp
2. Restore to this time: `sudo -u postgres pgbackrest --stanza=cluster --type=time --target="2023-12-28 17:19:10" restore`
3. Start PostgreSQL on primary: `systemctl start postgresql-15`

I have such lines in PostgreSQL logs:

```
[16-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  restored log file "00000003000000000000000C" from archive
[17-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  recovery stopping before commit of transaction 1018, time 2023-12-28 18:14:58.468349==
[18-1] user=,db=,app=,client= LOG:  pausing at the end of recovery
[19-1] user=,db=,app=,client= HINT:  Execute pg_wal_replay_resume() to promote.
```

So PostgreSQL is in recovery mode:

```
demo=# select pg_is_in_recovery();
 pg_is_in_recovery 
-------------------
 t
(1 row)
```

And I execute `pg_wal_replay_resume()` like it is said in the logs. `film` table exists as expected.

Then I try to attach standby:

```
sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-15/bin/repmgr -h 192.168.1.125 -U repmgr -d repmgr -f /etc/repmgr/15/repmgr.conf standby clone
systemctl start postgresql-15
sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-15/bin/repmgr standby register -F
```

When I check the status of the cluster it shows that something is wrong with standby:

```
[root@rocky2 ~]# sudo -u postgres /usr/pgsql-15/bin/repmgr -f /etc/repmgr/15/repmgr.conf cluster show
 ID | Name          | Role    | Status    | Upstream      | Location | Priority | Timeline | Connection string                         
----+---------------+---------+-----------+---------------+----------+----------+----------+--------------------------------------------
 1  | 192.168.1.125 | primary | * running |               | default  | 100      | 4        | host=192.168.1.125 user=repmgr user=repmgr
 2  | 192.168.1.126 | standby |   running | 192.168.1.125 | default  | 100      | 4        | host=192.168.1.126 user=repmgr user=repmgr

WARNING: following issues were detected
  - WAL replay is paused on node "192.168.1.126" (ID: 2) with WAL replay pending; this node cannot be manually promoted until WAL replay is resumed
```

What am I doing wrong? If I perform `select pg_wal_replay_resume();` the standby is promoted to the primary, but I don't do so.

So the question is: how to perform point-in-time recovery on the primary-slave setup properly?